# R.java was modified manually. Reverting to generated version

Tags: android

An error how to fix it?
R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
to drain setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
enter code here

package com.sposib.urav;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UravActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private EditText A;
private EditText B;
private EditText C;
private Button Clean;
private Button Solve;
private static final double ACCURACY=1000;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    A=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.a);
    B=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.b);
    C=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.c);
    Clean=(Button) findViewById(R.id.cl);
    Solve=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sl);
    Clean.setOnClickListener(this);
    Solve.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: What does this mean?  "to drain setContentView(R.layout.main);"

Comment: Delete the R file you edited, and if in eclipse; clean project (make sure auto building is on). Then it should work again... 
But really bad question.

Comment: Did you try in Eclipse ADT Android Tools->Fix Project Properties?

Answer (score 4):

AFAME, Pls do the following

1.Check the package name in manifest.

2.On the top menu, press Project>>Clean.

you will find the R.java generated.

Comment: @user1770497 one point??

Comment: @Satheesh +1 for these.These answer would be  a useful one

Answer (score 1):

The r.java file is auto generated as such you can't modify it on your own.  What you can do is provide the rest of the code so the error can be found.

Comment: @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v==Clean){
            A.setText("");
            B.setText("");
            C.setText("");
            A.requestFocus();
        }
        if (v==Solve){
            double a=0;
            double b=0;
            double c=0;
            double r1=0;
            double r2=0;

Comment: try{
                a=Double.parseDouble(A.getText().toString());
                b=Double.parseDouble(B.getText().toString());
                c=Double.parseDouble(C.getText().toString());
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.note6, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            double D;
            D=b*b-4*a*c;
            if (D<0){
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.note5, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

Comment: if (D==0){
                r1=Math.round(-b/(2*a)*ACCURACY)/ACCURACY;
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.note3)+" "+r1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (D>0){
                r1=Math.round((-b+Math.sqrt(D))/(2*a)*ACCURACY)/ACCURACY;
                r2=Math.round((-b-Math.sqrt(D))/(2*a)*ACCURACY)/ACCURACY;
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.note3)+" ( "+r1+" ; "+r2+" )", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by developer.android.com just re-run the complete code in eclipse by creating a new android project. It will generate the new R.java. Why do you want to edit R.java? You are not supposed to make any changes there!